# How to compare two columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, pandas-groupby

I have two series:

> count_by_ncm

```
0        1
61112000 1904
63026000 412
62052000 314
61051000 265
62092000 215
```

---

> count_by_ncm18:

```
ncm     quant  
1012100 1
1012900 1
1013000 1
1019000 1
1022110 1
```

I want to find the entries in the first column of `count_by_ncm` that don't exist in first column of `count_by_ncm18`

Comment: Use `count_by_ncm.loc[~count_by_ncm.ref.isin(count_by_ncm18.ref)]`

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'isin'